# OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync not getting hit

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am working on Microsoft.Bot.Builder for Teams for Search Message extension. My code is working fine in Local and Dev environment. But for production, I can see that OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync not even get hit. I did remote debugging, it never reaches there and also I dont see any logs as well. I see that code reaches to the constructor(TeamsBot : TeamsActivityHandler) only. and then back to BotController api endpoint await _adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, _bot);.

Can anyone help?  I am clueless here. My Bot id and password is correct , the api endpoint is on Https. This was working yesterday and now it stopped. Below are the logs:

2022-12-21 08:09:06.421 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://teams.Myonline.app/api/messages application/json;+charset=utf-8 1130
2022-12-21 08:09:06.421 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint 'My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp)'
2022-12-21 08:09:06.421 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Bot", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task PostAsync() on controller My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController (My.Office365.TeamsApp).
2022-12-21 08:09:06.422 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp) - Validation state: Valid
2022-12-21 08:09:06.422 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter: ProcessActivityAsync
2022-12-21 08:09:06.423 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action method My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 1.128ms.
2022-12-21 08:09:06.423 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp) in 1.4924ms
2022-12-21 08:09:06.423 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp)'
2022-12-21 08:09:06.423 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://teams.Myonline.app/api/messages application/json;+charset=utf-8 1130 - 401 - - 2.0425ms
2022-12-21 08:09:06.969 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET https://teams.Myonline.app/ - -
2022-12-21 08:09:06.970 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint '/_Host'
2022-12-21 08:09:06.970 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Route matched with {page = "/_Host", action = "", controller = ""}. Executing page /_Host
2022-12-21 08:09:06.970 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Valid
2022-12-21 08:09:06.970 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
2022-12-21 08:09:06.971 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Executed page /_Host in 1.0016ms
2022-12-21 08:09:06.971 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint '/_Host'
2022-12-21 08:09:06.971 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET https://teams.Myonline.app/ - - - 200 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 1.3705ms
2022-12-21 08:09:07.361 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST https://teams.Myonline.app/api/messages application/json;+charset=utf-8 1128
2022-12-21 08:09:07.361 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executing endpoint 'My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp)'
2022-12-21 08:09:07.361 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Route matched with {action = "Post", controller = "Bot", page = ""}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task PostAsync() on controller My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController (My.Office365.TeamsApp).
2022-12-21 08:09:07.361 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executing action method My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp) - Validation state: Valid
2022-12-21 08:09:07.361 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter: ProcessActivityAsync
2022-12-21 08:09:07.362 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action method My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp), returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EmptyResult in 1.2481ms.
2022-12-21 08:09:07.362 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Executed action My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp) in 1.4749ms
2022-12-21 08:09:07.362 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Executed endpoint 'My.Office365.TeamsApp.Controllers.BotController.PostAsync (My.Office365.TeamsApp)'
2022-12-21 08:09:07.363 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST https://teams.Myonline.app/api/messages application/json;+charset=utf-8 1128 - 401 - - 2.0420ms

Comment: What are the differences between your dev and prod environments? Are there any config details in the chain that still reference the dev environment?

Comment: No, they both are deployed through pipelines. All I can see is that everything is same.

Comment: Is there any console log you are getting?

Comment: I updated the original question.This is what I see in network trace:   Request URL: https://emea.ng.msg.teams.microsoft.com/v1/agents/xx/invoke
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 502   Response: {
  "errorCode": 1008,
  "message": "<BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code Unauthorized",
  "standardizedError": {
    "errorCode": 1008,
    "errorSubCode": 1,
    "errorDescription": "<BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code Unauthorized"}
}

Comment: Looks like you're getting 401 Unauthorized errors on the messaging endpoint. Something might be wrong with your keys somewhere or your Teams manifest.

Comment: I havent changed the menifest since long time. and the Bot id and secret is also not changed. Its always been there. The only change I did was deploying the new code after testing it on dev and locally. The bot was working on Dec 19 with same manifest and keys.

Comment: Could you please verify if you have configured correct [valid domains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains)?
Also refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was with wrong app settings. Key vault secrets were in appsettings.json instead just the url of appsettings.production.json.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is resolved.  Please add it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.